# Regex Pattern too long -- need split in JavaScript without escape characters

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I'm dealing with a really long regex pattern to match on and it's so long I'm going to have to split it up into several different strings.  My question is: How can I avoid the escape characters in JavaScript to instantiate a new RegExp to create a testable pattern?

In C# it's pretty simple: Just suffice the string with the `@` symbol and the compiler takes care of it. JavaScript is totally different and I'm not certain what the equivalent statement is.

Comment: Use a regex literal notation, `/\w+/`. Then, you'd need to call the `.source` property to access the pattern itself for concatenation (`/\w+/.source + /\s+/.source`).

Comment: The forward slash is what i am trying to avoid.  It's an "escape character"

Comment: Can you provide this regex?

Comment: @user1789573: You do not understand that `/.../` are not escaping characters, these are *regex delimiters*.

Comment: You alse can simplify your regexp, e.g. `(\s?\s?\s?\s?)` == `(\s{0,4})` ; `(\s{0,4})?` == `(\s{0,4})` etc

Comment: If your regex is longer than one line, regex is probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: You're not chatting, please stop using "w/" instead of "with".

Comment: Did you have a chance of checking my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a **regex literal notation**, e.g. `/\w+/`. Then, you'd need to call the `.source` property to access the pattern itself for concatenation purposes, e.g. `/\w+/.source + /\s+/.source`.

See more details about using [`RegExp` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Personally, I'd rather build a pattern from *string* blocks, where `\` should be doubled (e.g. `var word = "\\w+"; var spaces = "\\s+"; var pattern = word + spaces;`. This way, the overhead related to regex object construction will be avoided. It is up to you to choose the most convenient approach.